# symfony2 - Change layout at runtime

Tags: symfony, twig

Is possible in Symfony2 to change the layout (using twig) at runtime?

The layout should change based on a record fetched from a database, so I am thinking to implement a sort of LayoutManager that decides what layout to load for every request, but still I can't find a way to do this at runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Twig template

```
{% extends myLayoutName %}

{% block my_block_with_content %}
    Some content here
{% endblock %}
```

#### Controller

```
public function myAction() {
    $layoutName = '...'; // Calculate layout name

    return $this->render(
        'AcmeAcmeBundle::template_name.html.twig', 
       ['myLayoutName' => $layoutName]
    );
}
```